# Windows 10 hypervisor issue

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Hyper-V is reporting I don't have a hypervisor running, but all indications are that I do and my setup is correct. When trying to start a VM I get the message:

> Virtual machine '*xxx*' could not be started because the hypervisor is not running.

My system details are:

- **CPU:** Intel Core i9-9820X
- **Memory:** 128GB
- **Motherboard:** ASUS TUF X299 (latest firmware)
- **OS:** Windows 10 Pro 64Bit (1903)

I've checked and confirmed that all virtualization options in the BIOS are correct.

`systeminfo` reports:

```
Hyper-V Requirements: VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                    : Virtualization Enabaled In Firmware: Yes
                    : Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                    : Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

`bcedit` reports:

```
hypervisorlaunchtype Auto
```

`taskmgr` (Task Manager) reports:

```
Virtualization: Enabled
```

`services.msc` reports:

```
Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management: Running (Automatic)
```

I've tried removing and reinstalling Hyper-V (several times). All Hyper-V Windows Features are enabled.

I've tried running the command `bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto` and restarted, to no avail.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Check in the BIOS for any virtualization options that need enabling, perhaps found in *Advanced mode->Advanced tab->CPU Configuration-> Intel Virtualization Technology*, but may also be called SVM Mode or Secure Virtual Machine Mode or maybe use Optimized Defaults. This [Technet link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/iftekhar/2010/08/09/enable-hardware-settings-in-bios-to-run-hyper-v/) says that should be disabled: Intel VT-d (not VT-x), Trusted Execution.

Comment: Hyper-V isn't enabled/running if that's what systeminfo shows.  If Hyper-V is running, you should see: "Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed."

Comment: Are the Hyper-V host compute and Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management services running?

Comment: @essjae I can confirm that Hyper-V Host Compute and Hyper-V Virtual Management services are running.

Comment: @harrymc I can confirm that Intel VT-d has been disabled in the BIOS as instructed by the Technet article. Other virtual machine settings in the BIOS have been enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings seem correct but Hyper-V refuses to work.

I can only note that the specs for
[Intel Core i9-9820X](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/189121/intel-core-i9-9820x-x-series-processor-16-5m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html)
for Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) have this alarming note:

> This feature may not be available on all computing systems. Please check with the system vendor to determine if your system delivers this feature, or reference the system specifications (motherboard, processor, chipset, power supply, HDD, graphics controller, memory, BIOS, drivers, virtual machine monitor-VMM, platform software, and/or operating system) for feature compatibility. Functionality, performance, and other benefits of this feature may vary depending on system configuration.

It seems to me that something in your configuration, hardware or software,
has disabled virtualization, or is causing Hyper-V to fail.

I suggest to see if this is the same with other virtualization products, and
specifically [VMware](https://www.vmware.com/) and
[Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).
You would need to uninstall the Hyper-V role from Windows for them to work.

If none of these products work, then the problem is with your motherboard or BIOS
or some driver (usually the chipset driver) that is preventing vitualization
from functioning.

If any one of the products does work, then the problem is a bug in Hyper-V on
your configuration. You will need to verify that the product is truly using
virtualization and not emulation (if the information is not available inside
the product, one method might be to verify that the product can create
virtual machines for both 64 and 32-bits).

Comment: I've identified that the problem was with the BIOS. After a bit of digging, I've found an known issue with virtualization support on latest BIOS version of the ASUS TUF X299 motherboard. I've downgraded the BIOS and everything works.